# What is the best way to split a 1D tile map array into a 2D chunked array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm loading a set length 1D array that holds tile types as int. However, my visible map is built in chunks instead of a 2D [x][y] array. I have the engine and a tile class/object in order to build the map using Javascript.

I've tried a number of examples and nothing seems to quite fit, including a A-B to M-N conversion that just took the first tile and repeated it several times.

```
var chunks = [];

for (var y0 = 0; y0 < B; y0 += N) {
    for (var x0 = 0; x0 < A; x0 += M) {
        var chunk = [];
        for (var yd = 0; yd < N; yd++) {
            var y = y0 + yd;
            chunk[yd] = [];
            for (var xd = 0; xd < M; xd++) {
                var x = x0 + xd;
                chunk[yd][xd] = mapdata[y * A + x];
            }
        }
        chunks.push(chunk);
    }
}
```

Are there any better ways to convert the array output?

This snapshot of the map shows how it's laid out from TILED map data converted into a JSON array, and explains it better then the text examples I posted earlier could.

[image: Example Map]

Comment: All I see is xxx. Why don't you use a-z for your example so we can see how the 1d maps to the 2d?

Comment: so it's a plain 2D array with a carriage return every 24 square, no ? if so function tile(x,y) { return arr[x+y*25]; } is good enough.

Comment: How do you deal with the conversion from 24-15 down to 8-5? A 2D array is easy enough, but then the result has to be split up so it can be assigned to the tile containers. Each large container is one object that holds nine tiles, and is what is actually drawn out.